# securing rest web service with digest authentication java

Tags: java, rest, authentication, digest

I'm developing a rest client, with apache httpclient 4.3.3, which supports HTTP Basic and Digest authentication. **I need an example of rest webservice with digest authentication to test my client.** Can anyone help me, even an online rest web service could be very appreciated.

this is the client code for digest authentication:

```
final HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080, "http");
    final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));

    // Create AuthCache instance
    final AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    // Generate DIGEST scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
    DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
    // Suppose we already know the realm name
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "some-realm");
    // Suppose we already know the expected nonce value
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", "some-nonce");
    authCache.put(targetHost, digestAuth);

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);
```

after that, I can call:

```
RestClient genericRestClient = new GenericRestClient.Builder(METHOD_URL)
            .setUser(DEFAULT_USER).setPassword(DEFAULT_PASS)
            .setAuthType(AuthenticationType.DIGEST_AUTH)
            .setHttpVersion(HTTPVersion.HTTP_1_1).build();
    genericRestClient.doGet();
```

I need to cosume a rest web service with digest authentication to test my client.

I have begun with this web service:

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces("application/json")
public Product getProduct(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    .....

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("Product 1");
    product.setQty(50);

    return product;
```

thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Can you provide more details.

Comment: Such as .. what's the problem? There's no question.

Comment: I need an example of rest webservice with digest authentication to test my client. Even an online web service is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a good example [spring-security-rest-digest-auth](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-rest-digest-auth) with spring security that may help some of you.